# Deployment Of SAPUI5 Application on SAP HANA Server

Tags: sapui5

I was trying to find some article related to SAPUI5 application deployment on SAP Hana. I came across SAP HANA XSA Advanced utility but didn't any article mentioning the steps to do the deployment. So guys need your help related to this.

The thing I want to accomplish is I have created the UI5 WebApp & its targeted towards Desktop & Tablet & its developed using the SAPUI5 technology provided by SAPUi5. I want to host this site on SAP Hana & need to set the domain name & install the (**https**) certificate.

So how can I implement the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It basically depends on your version of HANA and also whether it is onPrem / SAP Cloud

For an onPrem HANA,

1. You can develop the application in either Eclipse IDE or WebIDE
2. Do Share Project > SAPUI5 ABAP Repository or Deploy -> Deploy to SAP UI5 ABAP Repository.
3. Make sure you select the right system before deployment.

In case of SAP HANA 2.0 / XSA, the deployment methodology differs.

1. The UI5/HTML5 application is created inside an MTA Project.
2. The MTA project is built in the WebIDE and is converted to an MTAR file.
3. This .mtar file is deployed into the XSA system using `xs deploy`
4. An associated route/URL `https://<hostname>:<port>/` for the application can be seen in the console as a part of the deployment.

Things are much simpler in SAP Cloud Platform/ SCP.

1. Open the WebIDE service. Create a SAPUI5 Project and deploy it to the SAP Cloud Platform.
2. Expose all your backend services as APIs using Destinations in SCP. The UI5 app talks to the backend APIs through destinations.
3. Once deployed and run you can access the app in the tenant URL. You could proceed to add a custom domain for account if need be.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... If i go with the option no 3 then which software i need to install on the sap hana server production server ? Like Web Ide.. Also can u pls tell how can i set ssl certificate to it ?

Comment: By option 3, You mean SAP cloud platform based deployment ? You don't have to install WebIDE in case of cloud. It is already **present as a service** which you can use right out of the box. In case of On Premise HANA installation, you can make use of this [link](https://help.sap.com/doc/PRODUCTION/370d1696f4a2466f9b6f022df8f5b853/2.0.00/en-US/SAP_Web_IDE_for_SAP_HANA_Installation_Guide_en.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of tutorials are available in the SAP Developer Center.

Here are few links.
[SAP HANA XS Advanced, Connecting to SAP Web IDE and cloning a Git Repository](https://www.sap.com/developer/tutorials/xsa-connecting-webide.html)
[SAPUI5 User Interface](https://www.sap.com/developer/tutorials/xsa-sapui5.html)